# Pre-filled Street, City, State etc in create/update contact (edit contact window)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

I want to pass Street, City, State of Address field to create new contact or update existing contact activity.

```
ArrayList<ContentValues> data = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();

ContentValues row1 = new ContentValues();
row1.put(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
row1.put(StructuredPostal.CITY, "mCity");
row1.put(StructuredPostal.COUNTRY, "mCountry");
row1.put(StructuredPostal.STREET, "mStreet");
row1.put(StructuredPostal.POSTCODE, "mPostCode");
data.add(row1);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, "9XXXXXXXXX");
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.COMPANY, "mCompanyName");
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.DATA, data);
startActivity(intent);
```

But here address is not visible in edit contact widow. Also I don't want to add contact directly using **ContentProviderOperation**. I want to show first edit contact window with above pre-filled fields.